# How to achive group by and order by in solr

Tags: solr, lucene, group-by, sql-order-by

We have requirement to achieve **group by** and **order by** simultaneously while implementing solr. How to achieve it? As per my investigation solr don't support both   simultaneously. Any one have good idea?

Answer (score 1):

Using field collapsing, you can set the sort order of groups and within groups using [group.sort and sort parameters](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/FieldCollapsing#Request_Parameters), respectively.